# fire wall fms rtmpt

Tags: flash, firewall, port, flash-media-server, rtmp

I have flash video player that is using fms server.
when  firewall is blocking port 1935(the default port) it takes about  30 second
to the video to be played. i try to force port 80 by rtmp protocol and try to connect to rtmpt 
protocol and both failed.   i checked the configuration file in fms and enabled port 80 and 1935 . 
The iis and fms are listenning both to port 80, and there is no conflict.

i have no idea what else to check ? (maybe the syntax of forcing the port is wrong :
rtmp://212.235.12.143/vod:80 or rtmp::80//212.235.12.143/vod or rtmp://212.235.12.143:80/vod?)

Comment: Did you ever find out how to fix this ? I'm really curious as I'm having the same issue right now. Thanks

Comment: @ Theo.T - answered about connecting to FMS on port 80

Answer (score 0):

- check if port 80 is allowed in `%FMS_install_folder%\conf\fms.ini` (should be by default)
- on the client side: `netConnection.connect('rtmp://localhost/vod/:80');`
  when such client connects i see `vod :80` in administration console so it seems to be ok